# Migrating .pb from Tensorflow 1.14 to 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run the FaceNet model in Tensorflow 2.0. I have a downloaded a pretrained set of weights (.pb file) and used to load the graph in TF 1.14 using tf.GraphDef().

I am wondering how I am supposed to run this in TF 2.0:

I tried using the tf.SavedModel.load() method but this returns an empty signatures dictionary.

Is it possible to reuse a TF 1.x pb file in with the new Tensorflow 2.0 release? and if so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, according to this: https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/sigs/testing/faq.md it would seem that

"frozen graph generated from a TensorFlow 1.x model WONT work in TF 2.0"

I did find a way of converting the model to a saved Model:

```html
class Net(object):

    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.model_filepath = model_path
        self.load_graph(model_filepath=self.model_filepath)


    def load_graph(self, model_filepath):
        print("Loading model...")


        with tf.gfile.GFile(model_filepath, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
                tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
                signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
                    inputs={'image_batch':graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_batch:0'),
                            'phase_train': graph.get_tensor_by_name('phase_train:0')},
                    outputs={'embeddings': graph.get_tensor_by_name('embeddings:0')}
                )
                builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("./Output/")
                builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                    sess=sess,
                    tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                    signature_def_map={'serving_default': signature}
                )
                builder.save()


Net(path_to_pb_file)
```